# c++ pass various arguments to parent class constructor (thread c++11)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Who knows how to pass arguments from inherited class to the basic class constructor, which accept various number of arguments? I mean... "thread" class have an initialization constructor with various number of arguments, it's represented like:

```
template <class Fn, class... Args> explicit thread (Fn&& fn, Args&&... args);
```

So... I want to create an inherited class with same initialization constructor and constructor in new class must pass all arguments to basic (thread) class, but don't know how =)

For example (what I want):

```
class my_thread : public std::thread {
private:
    .....
public:
    my_thread( WHAT TO WRITE HERE? ) : thread (AND HERE ) {};
    .....
};

void my_func(int arg_1, char arg_2) {
    .....
}

int main() {
    my_thread mt(my_func, 20, -6);
    mt.join();
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class Fn, class... Args,
          class = typename std::enable_if<
                  !std::is_same<typename std::decay<Fn>::type,
                                my_thread>::value>::type>
explicit my_thread (Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) 
       : thread(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
```

The usual caveats about inheriting from standard library types apply. The `enable_if` removes this constructor from overload resolution if you pass a `my_thread`, in essence repeating the resolution of [LWG 2097](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2097).

Comment: You should also add my_thread(my_thread&) = delete; to avoid accidentally passing a non-const reference to my_thread to the base class.

Comment: @Nevin So basically it's the similar concern as [LWG 2097](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2097)?

Comment: @T.C. Basically, yes.  It's a very general gotcha.  The non-const lvalue reference is always a better match to the templated constructor (because it requires no conversions) than to the copy constructor (which requires a non-const to const conversion), so you always have to be a little bit careful in the presence of templated constructors.